# Why does UpdatePanel poll the server every 10 seconds, and can I make it stop?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

Implementing partial page updates with UpdatePanel was fairly straight forward, but at 300 bytes per request 6 times a minute that's more than 2.5MB per day, which could be prohibitive for those paying by the byte for connectivity.  Since updates to my page are driven strictly by client side interactivity I can't imagine why such polling would be necessary (nor even advantageous, really.)  Can this behavior be disabled?

Comment: What poll every 10 seconds? you're not making any sense... Polling every x seconds is not default (or non default for that matter) UpdatePanel behavior.

Comment: My bad, it's a VS thing, "browserLink", apparently runs script in the browser context, and the requests are showing up in Chrome developer tools.  I'd never seen it before adding an UpdatePanel... which was about exactly the same time that I upgraded to VS 2015.  Dhould I delete this question?

Comment: Not needed, future readers that see the same 10 second poll can now read that it is a VS thing.